# как подогнать длину колонок

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

колонки не равны по длине на одном экране левая больше на экране с другим разрешением правая больше. Я понимаю что я намешал тут все, есть ли шанс из этого вылезти

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="row">
      
  <div class="col col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xl-6" role="main">
  <div style="border: 1px solid #fed000;
    border-radius: 4.2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: #FFFFFF;">
                      </div>
                      </div>
  

    <div class="col">
      <div class="video-container" style="margin-bottom:66px;">
        <iframe style=" border: 5px solid #fed000;
    border-radius: 4.2px;
    box-shadow: 5px 8px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)">
</iframe>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="border: 1px solid #fed000;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4.2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
</div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
сверху блоков все нормально они на одной линии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а снизу они расходятся при изменении разрешения это видно еще больше

Comment: Ого)) Пробуйте box-sizing , и тег айфрейма не закрыт.  А вообще CSS в тегах плохая идея изначально. Вы же классов не видите где пропустили или лишние дописали из-за каши стилей)))

Comment: Согласен с автором выше, что css в тегах это плохая идея. Как вариант решения можно задать минимальную высоту для этих блоков

Comment: @aquido, я с вами полностью согласен на счет css но так уже получилось, не стоило так делать. Есть еще какие нибудь  варианты((

Comment: да, я с вами полностью согласен, я только учусь поэтому так вышло. У вас есть еще какие нибудь идеи? @RomanStoliarenko

Comment: Ну как сказать. Попробуйте не лепить все в одно место и сразу, а разберитесь с сеткой бутстрап (как раз 4 версия вышла из беты 19-го числа). Пара видео по бутстрапу и все станет на свои места, потом уже добавляйте CSS, только не инлайн, это плохая привычка. Привыкайте сразу писать отдельным файлом или как минимум в теге style. И добавляйте стили поочередно, проверяя. Марджины и паддинги мерзкие ребята. Их надо понять и простить, и не забывать о полезном,  иногда, box-sizing. Лучше для обучения брать какой-то структурированный видео-курс (платный/бесплатный), и поурочно все пробовать руками.

Comment: Идея заключается в том что этот пример плохой. Проще и быстрее его написать, чем править. Но если вам напишут, вы ничего не поймете в основах. А это важно понимать. Так что лучше удалите этот пример, и напишите его после пары тройки видео уроков по бутстрапу и CSS (только не те что по 10 минут, а нормальных уроков). Вы будете удивлены на сколько все просто.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rz9r6cywVzU Вот базовый урок, который должен помочь поправить вам сетку. Препод нудный, но все понятно и подробно. А после уже добавляйте стили и следите что портит разметку.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас посмотрю @RomanStoliarenko

Comment: Это по 3-му бутстрапу. Но урок очень простой и подробный. Основные понятия только, остальные уроки у них платные. Есть курс и по 4-му, но еще не добрался до него))